# Different results when using SUMIF() and SUMPRODUCT()

Tags: excel-2007, excel-formula

This really bugged us for quite some time and even though we have found how to get the correct result, we really want to know why `SUMIF` yields incorrect results while `SUMPRODUCT` yields exact results when using the same conditions.

Here are both formulaes:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Calcul!$J$2:$J$15000=Sommaire!J2)*(Calcul!$K$2:$K$15000))
=SUMIF(Calcul!$J$2:$J$15000,Sommaire!J2, Calcul!$K$2:$K$15000)
```

As you can see: exact same range, exact same comparison, exact same sum range.

A little more about the data: in both sheets ('Sommaire' and 'Calcul') the cells contain data that is akin to a serial number containing only numbers but treated as text. This number is made from concatenating data from columns A, B, C, D, E and I such that the formula is:

```
=IFERROR(A2&B2&C2&D2&E2&I2, "ERREUR")
```

Using filters in 2 different ways (filtering directly the key or "serial number" and the second to filter directly each components of the key) we get the exact same data set which, when computed by hand, gives us the same value as that which `SUMPRODUCT` returned.

Any ideas ? We really can't come up with any reason why the results returned are different.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. This is only for the key part, the data itself is numbers only (cash).

Comment: I doubt it because we do set the key part as text because we need the zero in front. If we set the cell as number it will trim that 0 since it becomes useless. Maybe this is what happens internally if `SUMIF` does convert the text number to a... numerical number (for lack of a better expression).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally found the solution. It seems that for some reason `SUMIF` forces treatment of numeric strings of characters as numbers anyway. Being that our key is fairly large, it's not impossible that it's reaching some kind of integer capacity and overflowing. If we just append a letter in front of it, we get the same result as when we are using `SUMPRODUCT`.

Examples of keys that overflowed:

```
01003046014910111616
01000145950198116308
```

And those keys, with the exact same formula (just a C was appended in front), return the expected results:

```
C01003046014910111616
C01000145950198116308
```